# youtube embedding in an HTML5 code

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, rss

`<tr>
  <th>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="'+link1+'?autoplay=1;" frameborder="0"     allowfullscreen type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always"></iframe>
  </th>
</tr>`

where link1 = http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPDW7hj1yfs

But my iframe is not displaying anything.
Please help and tell where I am going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is the following:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QZTArNJYHLU?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The problem may simply be how you are injecting the link into the embed code.